# Phone emulator in Visual Studio 2015 RC on Windows 10 preview build 10074 does not work

Tags: emulation, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I had some problem in running some Phone of the emulators in VS2015 RC so I tried to install also the "Pre-release Microsoft Emulator for Windows 10 Mobile" and then also the external SDK ...

Now, even thought I uninstalled the external Windows 10 SDK and made a "repair" of VS2015 RC, no one of the phone emulators stars (it goes till the "OS is starting" phase and then remain in that state till, after many minutes, the emulator crashes and some time a popup says "The emulator is unable to get the sensor states from the device: Operation failed because connection is shut down", ... most of the times no error is reported).

I also tried to delete in the Hyper-V manager both the created emulators virtual machines and the related  Virtual Switches related to Windows Phone Emulator Internal: these are recreated at the next run of the emulator from VS, but nothing changed ...

Any suggestion? How can I make at least some of the phone emulators work properly?

Regards

Enzo

Comment: I've had this same issue; the team is currently investigating it. I'll post again if there is a good work-around (rather than "wait for a future flight"). Thanks for reporting the issue; in the future you can post bugs using the Windows Feedback tool (there's a section for Developer Platform).